# CSS clear:both not working

Tags: css, xhtml

I seem to be having issues getting my layout to clear properly. Look at [this](http://www.digiflip.tv/Rant-and-Rave)

I can't stop the item in the left column from pushing down the items in the right. Can anyone help?

<strike>[Screenshot with some pointy arrows](http://www.digiflipconcepts.com/temporary-images/float-issues.jpg)</strike> (Dead link)

Comment: It's working for me What browser are you using? Could be an IE 6 double margin bug on floated elements

Comment: I'm using Firefox 3 for Mac, I see it is even worse for IE7 on PC! :(, will post a image...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem markup/style appears to be:

```
<div class="clear" />
```

This is clearing the float in your left hand div which creates the gap between your post and teaser sections.

```
myblog.css (line 166)

#myBlog-wrap div.clear {
clear:right; <--- problem clear
height:1px;
line-height:1px;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

[Here's how firefox 3 renders the page with the clear disabled.](http://i59.photobucket.com/albums/g311/squidsoup/fixedrendering.png)

Unrelated to your question, but you also seem to have some IE specific css issues to resolve as well. Definitely consider making a conditional ie.css for your site :)

Comment: I removed it but it made no difference so I put it back. Maybe it is the <div class="clear"/> code. I shall investigate...

Comment: thanks, you are a legend that has fixed it :) - a thousand thank you's!

Comment: yes, just noticed the IE errors anomalies, i shall try and fix them